# System Calls From C Code

Tags: raspbian, python, c, security, password

after many searches and tries, finally I found a way to protect my python code on my raspberry pi (for sure there is no 100% security), but let's say I made it a little bit harder.

This method still needs a small modification to complete. I can post what I need only, but I preffered to post the whole procedure in case someone else get the benifit of it.

I have the following python script: test.py
I have encrypted this script using the following command:

```
gpg -c test.py
```

Then it asked me to enter a password twice:
and I set the password suppose it is 123456

I removed test.py, and I left the new encrypted file test.py.gpg

till now everything is working true just as I want, and now I have an encrypted python script.

now to execute this file I should decrypt it, execute it and then remove it.
so if I Type:

```
gpg test.py.gpg
```

it prompts me to enter the password
then I entered the password
then it recreates the original file named test.py
and then I can execute it using the command:
    sudo python test.py
and so keeping the program running and remove it using
    sudo rm test.py

now to call this script, I created a small C program, as this is the only way to call it with keeping the password hidden from intruders (except super genius intruders :) ).

in this program I just wrote these simple lines:

```
system("sudo gpg gpgTest.py.gpg");
system("123456"); //The password
system("sudo python gpgTest.py");
system("sudo rm gpgTest.py");
```

when I try to execute this c program, it prompt me to enter the password, which means the second line is not doing the job.
so how can I modify the above code, so that I call the decryption command and wait until the system ask for password then pass password to it, and complete the execution of the rest code?

In another way, all I need is to execute the encrypted python code from the c program, without the need to enter the password, as the password must be passed inside the C code.

I just noticed another issue, is that calling system to execute the program would not allow the rm command to do it jobs until execution ended. What I really need, is to open another instance of system calls to execute the rm command directly after executing the the python script.

Comment: You might be interested in knowing that `rm` doesn't actually erase files from the disk, it simply marks them as "removed". Removed files can easily be recovered with `extundelete` and similar tools.

Comment: and I'll be interested more if you know any command other than rm to completely erase files

Comment: I think this will do the job: [4 Tools to Securely Delete Files from Linux](http://linoxide.com/security/delete-files-permanatly-linux/)

Comment: Yes, `srm` command looks good. But don't expect your setup to provide good protection anyway. Check my answer.

Comment: If internet connection is available on the targeted systems, I suggest you to focus on license server setup. You wrapper written in C can communicate with this server for secrets.

Comment: @vaha If internet connection is available, it's much more secure to implement this as [SaaS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_as_a_service). Then you don't have to hide your code because you never distribute it.

Comment: hay guys, I'm from lebanon, and it's impossible to depends on internet while you are in lebanon.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev, your thought is not acceptable for the universal set, you look through narrow window. There are tons of applications which are not suitable for to be SaaS. Even think about a very simple Python script which makes some arithmetic based on the system info or does some modifications on the system. There is no good for being web/remote based.

Comment: @vaha That's what they said about text editors, yet look at Office365! It has nothing to do with being good, it's primarily a piracy deterrent.

Comment: Note that someone would only need to replace `python` with `cat` no matter how you try to secure your python script.

Comment: @v7d8dpo4 You mean cat the file before it is deleted? If so, I'm trying to make it harder as much as I can by using a complex path. if you mean something else please let me know

Comment: @Dani No. I mean to replace the file `/usr/bin/python` with the program `cat`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to provide input for a command, you should do it via input substitution or pipes, like this:

```
system("echo 123456 | gpg --passphrase-fd 0 gpgTest.py.gpg");
system("gpg --passphrase-fd 0 gpgTest.py.gpg < (echo 123456)");
```

Check out [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60213/gpg-asks-for-password-even-with-passphrase) for the explanation about `--passphrase-fd 0`.

If you need to continue execution without waiting for the command to complete, add an `&` character to it, like this:

```
system("sudo python gpgTest.py&");
```

Though in that case you'll have to make sure `python` has a chance to read the file before you remove it.

Be aware that `rm` doesn't really erase files, you should use `srm`, `wipe` or `shred` instead. Also, hiding a password inside a C file is a polichinelle's secret: simply running `strings a.out` will reveal your password in cleartext.

Comment: Seems perfect! but after testing it, it still prompt me to enter the password!

Comment: Though in that case you'll have to make sure python has a chance to read the file before you remove it (I think using sleep(1); will do the job)

Comment: @Dani this is probably because of `sudo`. Dump it from everywhere and run your C program with `sudo` instead.

Comment: I think this is the near best solution for scripting languages.

Comment: It works! Thanks @Dmitry Grigoryev. Still two things, first if I tried to end the execution in terminal by (ctl +C) it ends and automatically starts again. Second is what you said (simply running strings a.out will reveal your password in cleartext.), does using numeric password and storing it with integer variables and then passing them by calling variable names prevent intruders from getting the benefit of strings a.out command?

Comment: @Dani I can't tell why your code would start again, not with the lines you have provided. On your second point, yes: constructing password string on the fly will make it somewhat harder to extract, but not impossible. Running `strings a.out` won't help, but `strace a.out` would still log your password during a `printf` call, although the log would be huge and harder to analyse. In the end, if you can't deny people debugging your program you're fighting a losing battle.

Comment: The problem is with the & charecter. When I removed it, it never stopped again, but now I can't delete the file befor ending the app execution

Comment: (although the log would be huge and harder to analyse) That's all I want: make it harder. because I know security is always a losing battle. suppose that you are interested in extracting the password using strace a.out, how much you expect it would take with you?

Comment: @Dani Hard to say, perhaps 15 minutes. Which is 15 time better than `strings` log which usually fits on one screen for small programs. Still, not that much.

Comment: I have three ideas then. First of all, I'll fill this small program with a very huge code, I mean thousands of lines and methods to make it bigger and harder with no any other purpose. Second, I'll use non friendly names for variables and methods. Finally as I'm going to use numeric password, I can write complex algorithms and equations to reach the final value. which means that the password is not stored it is only calculated according to another stored tenths of variables. In this case how much time would you think it will cost you?(sorry for wasting your time, but u r the first real helper)

Comment: @Dani Sorry to disappoint you, but that won't change much. You will still have to write the password clear text to STDOUT (or pass it to `system`), and that's where `strace` will capture it. Of course, if you make it twisted enough, it can take days to analyse, but you'll also spend days implementing it. That's why e.g. putting superglue on the SD card is a thing: you only spend a second per card, while getting the card out of it takes time and tools.

Comment: You are not disappointing me, you are warning about all risks. without your notes about strings a.out command, I thought it's enough to store it with a string. with respect to super glue, this is not enough since I have to boot raspberry without authentication. So, intruder in my case can just connect a screen, kyb and mouse and have access without removig the sd card. I'll search and try to understand how strace works, and then I can have more chances to make it harder. Do you think there could be holes other than strace?

Comment: @Dani It also would be quite easy to alias `cat` as `python` in the PATH and directly have a look at your code whenever your C program tries to run it.

Comment: @TonioElGringo But my python files are encrypted! Did you read my post details and descriptions above?

Comment: @Dani I did. I am saying, your proposed program decrypts the python files and pass them to a "python" program. It would be easy to provide a _fake_ program called python that simply outputs the program or store it in a file.

Comment: @TonioElGringo: I am decrypting the python fiiles, running them and then and removing them directly.. You mean that any one can make a program that copy the decrypted files before they get removed! do you think that using another path, hiding it well on C program with char variables despite of strings, and making a complex path among hundreds of dir's contain same folders with same file names, and many other procedures will make it harder. again and again, I understand very well that there is no 100% security, all I need to achieve is about 30% or 40%.

Comment: @TonioElGringo: Do you know any linux-based method, that allows me block any running terminal command other than mine in c program, before decrypting python files, and then unblock them after encrypting my files again?

Comment: @Dani Just add a password for your user and use files permissions.